# Style A Disabled Twitter Bootstrap Table Onclick Of An Option Contained In The Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page which uses a Bootstrap 3 table.  this table contains various link but what I want it to disable the table links when an option is selected.

I have this working but I need to style it so that the front end user knows the table is disabled.

My code is:

```
                <table class="table table-hover table-striped hidden-xs" id="clientListTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="<%=Html.GenerateLoopBackUrl(true, new { ClientList_SortOn = cell.SortOn, ClientList_SortDirection = sortDirection })%>"><%=cell.Value%></a>
                        <%if (showFilterOption)
                            { %> 
                                <a href="#" id="<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_link" class="noPdf">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" id="<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_img"></span>
                                </a>
                                <%--<img src="<%= filterIcon%>" alt="add filter" id="<%:cell.ColumnIdentifier%>_img" />--%>
                        <%}%>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <%
                        foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
                        {
                                if (cell.Hidden) { }
                                else {%><td onclick="return clickDisableFunction();"><%=cell.Value%></td><%}
                        }
                    %>
                </tr>
```

And my Java is

```
    var clickedOnce = false;

function clickDisableFunction()
{
    if (clickedOnce == true)
    {
        return false;
    };
    clickedOnce = true;
    document.getElementById('clientListTable').setAttribute("disabled","true")
};
```

As I said this works as expected but when a user clicks a link they have no visual that all other links have been disabled while they are being redirected.

Below is a screenshot of the table in question.
[image]

All I want is to make the table fade out (turn a light grey on a link click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use the modal as an option which works fine